# Typescript: type inference for children on generic react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Given a react component that is generic on two properties, a `load` function returning type `T`, and the children (which is a single function taking a parameter of type `T`)...

```
class Test<T> extends React.Component<{
  load: () => T;
  children: (r: T) => JSX.Element;
}> {
  render() {
    return this.props.children(this.props.load());
  }
}
```

typescript is not able to infer the type of `res` from the return value of `load`, it defaults to type `{}`.

```
<Test load={() => ({ test: 'x' })}>
  {res =>
    <span>
      {res.test}
    </span>}
</Test>;
```

Is this a bug, or is typescript not able to infer based on return values -- as it looks like typing of JSX children is supported.

EDIT:

for background, the usecase is creating a "lazy" component which accepts `load` function which return a promise resolving to some further JSX.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** In the meantime TypeScript has been improved, such that the code given in the question automatically infers the type for `res`. I haven't checked which change was responsible for that, but I guess it happened somewhere around 3.0-3.3.

---

I think the problem is that your code gets transpiled to something similar to:

```
React.createElement(
  Test,
  {load: () => ({ test: 'x' })},
  res =>
    <span>
      {res.test}
    </span>
)
```

From that situation it is more clear that it would be very hard for the compiler/definitions to correctly infer the generic parameter. In your situation it would be enough to tip the compiler:

```
<Test load={() => ({ test: 'x' })}>
    {(res: { test: string }) =>
        <span>
            {res.test}
        </span>}
</Test>
```

Comment: good point, maybe TS will add some JSX specific typing support for this stuff in the future.

Comment: I've just come across this issue and I'd like to do it in such a way that I don't have to specify the type on the children manually, is there any way to infer this now with the latest version of TypeScript please?

Comment: I've just checked it, at least by using Typescript 3.3 the code in the question works, automatically inferring the type for `res`.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work when you add parameters to load method though: `<Test load={({ test })=>({ test1: test })}>{({ test1 })=>(<span>{test1}</span>)}</Test>` states that `test1` that out of the Test component is of type `any`...grrr!

Comment: But then you are using a different type for load? Because the initial one (`() => T`) has no function argument.

Comment: @Stephan Yes, sorry, in my case I have added a parameter for load, and I've added it to the props for Test component too so it is required, but as soon as you add a parameter with any type value, this breaks the inferrence for some reason?